# Anisotropic scaling in geometric/Clifford algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

Take the geometric algebra over $\Bbb R^n$. Suppose we have a blade multivector in this algebra. Now we want to anisotropically scale this multivector.

Is there a general closed-form expression for performing this operation?

I have found similar things for other operations (rotation and etc), but not anisotropic scaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anisotropic scaling is a linear transformation on $\Bbb R^n$ and thus has a well defined [outermorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outermorphism) on $\mathcal G^n$.  So if $S$ is your scaling function and $A = a_1 \wedge a_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge a_k$ is your $k$-blade, then $S(A) = S(a_1)\wedge S(a_2)\wedge \cdots \wedge S(a_k)$.

Answer (score 1):

The transformation of a single vector is fairly simple. Scaling by a factor of $k$ in the direction of vector $n$ is done by

$$S(a) = ka_\parallel + a_\perp = \big(k(a\cdot n) + (a\wedge n)\big)n^{-1}$$

The transformation $S(A)$ of a multivector $A$ is the outermorphism of this. (See the other answer.)